# NSUUID().UUIDString values changing on Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uuid

I learned that `UUIDString` was an unique value, but I don't know if the values still the same, on `Xcode` when I run the app, the value change, it's normally ?

Edit:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //        Sauvegarde UUID

        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if userDefaults.objectForKey("ApplicationUniqueIdentifier") == nil {
            let UUID = NSUUID().UUIDString
            userDefaults.setObject(UUID, forKey: "ApplicationUniqueIdentifier")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
        }

        print(String(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ApplicationUniqueIdentifier")))
}
```

Look my edit I found a swift solution but, it print: `Optional(generatedid)` how to delete `Optional()` and just get the `id ?`

Answer (score 2):

> UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique Identifiers) or IIDs (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit values. UUIDs created by NSUUID conform to RFC 4122 version 4 and are created with random bytes.

Yes, NSUUID will have different value for every new instance. It used to generate unique identifiers - if you need one, create new instance and then store it's value somewhere for later use.

Comment: Look my edit I found a swift solution but, it print: `Optional(generatedid)` how to delete `Optional()` and just get the id ?

Comment: use ! after the variable name or post code if posible

Comment: there is couple ways, if you're sure that value is not nil just use `!` as mentioned above (i.e. `optionalValue!`) but beware that it'll crash on `nil`. if value can be `nil` use `if let` i.e. `if let value = optionalValue { /*do something*/ }` or something like this `let value = optionalValue ?? "defaultValue"`

Answer (score 0):

You can create get vendor ID from UDID string once and save it in key chain and use it later.
I implemented this as follows:

```
NSString *Appname = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
    NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:Appname account:@""];
    if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
    {
        strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
        [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:Appname account:@""];
    }
    return strApplicationUUID;
```

Comment: Look my edit I found a swift solution but, it print: `Optional(generatedid)` how to delete `Optional()` and just get the id ?

Comment: you can use exclamation mar (!) to get the value without optional string. But User defaults get cleared when you uninstall your app from device.